# R: filter non missing data on many (but not all) columns

Tags: r, filter, pipe, na, missing-data

have the following data frame lets call it `df`, with the following observations

| id | b | c | f | e_7 | ic_107 | d | g | j |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 3 | 66 | 97 | 8 | 5 | 7 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 7 | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 3 | NA | 2 | 79 | 5 | 5 | 4 | 9 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 2 | 32 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 36 | 6 | 9 | 49 | 9 | NA | NA | NA |
| 6 | 0 | 2 | 32 | 1 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 7 | 36 | NA | NA | 49 | 9 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I want to retain only the records which do not have NA in many, but not all, columns. Let's say, column b, c, d, g, and j.

I am currently using `filter` with `pipes`, but I would like to avoid coding like:

```
df_new <- df %>%
  filter(!is.na(b))%>%
  filter(!is.na(c))%>%
  filter(!is.na(d))%>%
  filter(!is.na(g))%>%
  filter(!is.na(j))
```

Is there an easier way to write the code?

In this example, I have 5 columns for the filtering condition. In my real dataset, I have 17. Therefore, I would like to avoid the coding above.

Also, instead of simple column names `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`..., the columns of my real dataset have long names, such as `lighteningdate`, `depression`,`anxiety`..., so I'd like to use a vector of column numbers (`c(3:9, 13:21)`)rather than a list of column names in the coding.

Comment: filter(across(everything(),
                ~ !is.na(.)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `filter` with `if_all`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
    filter(if_all(c(b, c, d, g, j), negate(is.na)))
#   id  b c  f e_7 ic_107 d g j
#1  1 23 3 66  97      8 5 7 0
#2  4  0 2 32   1      6 6 1 0
#3  6  0 2 32   1      6 7 8 9
```

---

Or specify the index

```
df %>%
    filter(if_all(c(2:3, 7:9),  ~ !is.na(.)))
```

Or with `complete.cases`

```
df %>%
   filter(if_all(c(2:3, 7:9),  complete.cases))
```

which would be similar to `base R` option

```
df[complete.cases(df[c(2:3, 7:9)]),]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:7, b = c(23L, 1L, NA, 0L, 36L, 0L, 36L), 
    c = c(3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, NA), f = c(66L, 5L, 79L, 32L, 
    9L, 32L, NA), e_7 = c(97L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 49L, 1L, 49L), ic_107 = c(8L, 
    NA, 5L, 6L, 9L, 6L, 9L), d = c(5L, NA, 4L, 6L, NA, 7L, 0L
    ), g = c(7L, NA, 9L, 1L, NA, 8L, 0L), j = c(0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 
    NA, 9L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L
))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! These are all good answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rowSums` to count number of `NA` values in each row and select only those rows which have no `NA`'s.

```
cols <- c(2, 3, 7:9)
subset(df, rowSums(is.na(df[cols])) == 0)

#  id  b c  f e_7 ic_107 d g j
#1  1 23 3 66  97      8 5 7 0
#2  4  0 2 32   1      6 6 1 0
#3  6  0 2 32   1      6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- tribble(~id,  ~b, ~c, ~f, ~e_7,   ~ic_107,    ~d, ~g, ~j,
              1,    23, 3,  66, 97, 8,  5,  7,  0,
              2,    1,  1,  5,  7,  NA, NA, NA, NA,
              3,    NA, 2,  79, 5,  5,  4,  9,  0,
              4,    0,  2,  32, 1,  6,  6,  1,  0,
              5,    36, 6,  9,  49, 9,  NA, NA, NA,
              6,    0,  2,  32, 1,  6,  7,  8,  9,
              7,    36, NA, NA, 49, 9,  0,  0,  1)


df %>% filter(map_int(split(is.na(select(df,b,c,d,g,j)),1:nrow(df)),sum)<=2L)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `across(c(.,.,.))`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(across(c(a,b,c), ~ !is.na(.)))
  a b  c  d
1 2 5 10 NA
2 3 6  7  3
```

Mock data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = c(NA,1,2,3,NA),
  b = c(4,NA,5,6,7),
  c = c(8,9,10,7,6),
  d = c(NA,NA,NA,3,7)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option using `subset` + `is.na` + `rowMeans`

```
> subset(df, !is.na(rowMeans(cbind(b, c, d, g, j))))
  id  b c  f e_7 ic_107 d g j
1  1 23 3 66  97      8 5 7 0
4  4  0 2 32   1      6 6 1 0
6  6  0 2 32   1      6 7 8 9
```